# SQLite invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive] in CPP

Tags: c, sqlite

Need to update database by new value (Name and Address) provided by the user.The error in query is that:

1. error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]   sqlite3_bind_text(res, 2, *c2)

   2. error: too few arguments to function ‘int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int, void (*)(void*))’
           sqlite3_bind_text(res, 2, *c2)

my code is:

```
        const char *c1 = updatedName.c_str();
        const char *c2 = updatedAdd.c_str();

char *sql = ("UPDATE RECORDS SET NAME = ? AND ADDRESS = ? WHERE ACCOUNT_No = ?");
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
        sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, *c1);
        sqlite3_bind_text(res, 2, *c2);
        sqlite3_bind_int(res, 3, acc);
        rc = sqlite3_step(res);
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
```

Comment: 2. The compiler is telling you that `sqlite3_bind_text` takes 5 arguments but you only provide 3, so 2 arguments are missing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is throwing too few arguments to function ‘int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int, void (*)(void*))’
             sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, c1, 0); this error

Comment: sorry, a function must be passed as last arg. Check the documentation... some example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927188/sqlite3-bind-text-on-select-different-result-on-prepared-vs-string-sql-statemen

Comment: 1. This is perhaps because of argument mis-match, when not enough arguments were supplied. As Jean-François said, please read the man pages.

Comment: also, `*c1` and `*c2` are of type `const char` and the function ask for `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_bind_text()` wants a pointer to the entire string, not only the first character. (You need to understand how C pointers and strings (character arrays) work.)

And the [`sqlite3_bind_text()` documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) tells you to use five parameters:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, updatedName.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```